# JS not adding row to table

Tags: javascript, html

I consoled out the value that goes into the form. That is correct. It return as an a string.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqtPp.png)

```
const saveList = () => {
    const inputListNameText = inputListName.value;

    fetch('/api/lists', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ list_name: inputListNameText }),
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(inputListNameText);

            const tableBody = document.querySelector('#tbody');
            const newRow = document.createElement('tr');
            const listCell = document.createElement('td');

            listCell.textContent = inputListNameText.value;
            newRow.appendChild(listCell);
            tableBody.appendChild(newRow);
        })
}
```

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sm table-bordered">
                                <thead class="thead-dark">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Task</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="tbody">
                                    <tr id="list-container">
                                        <th scope="row"><input class="todo__checkbox" type="checkbox"></th>
                                        <td class="text-break"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

I made sure the data is coming through correctly.

Comment: `const inputListNameText = inputListName.value;` is probably a `string` isn't it? But later on you set `listCell.textContent = inputListNameText.value;` but as `inputListNameText` is a string, `inputListNameText.value` is `undefined`. Thus you are setting te content of your table cell to undefined, and depending on your styling, it therefore probably won't be visible. Use the Dom inspector to verify whether the row was created or not

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in the image, the row is added but the text content seems null.

**You can try changing**

```js
listCell.textContent = inputListNameText.value;
```

**with**

```js
listCell.textContent = inputListNameText;
```